# Contractable Metric Spaces Homeomorphic to Euclidean Space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness, metric-geometry

Is there a characterization of all metric spaces which are homeomorphic to a contractable subset of Euclidean space?

This question is cross-referenced [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331742/contractable-metric-spaces-homeomorphic-to-euclidean-space).

Comment: Of Euclidean space of which dimension? Some dimension? Do you assume at least local compactness of your spaces? Also, in the title you say "contractible" but in the body of the question only "simply connected". Which one do you mean?

Comment: I am looking for any finite euclidean space which contains a contractable copy of the (locally compact) metric space.

Comment: Every finite dimensional compact metrizable space embeds in some $E^n$.

Comment: but how to characterize the contractable ones?

Comment: Contractible means contractible.

Comment: Oh okay, so they're no well known "metric characterization"?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. You asked a topological question. Contractibility is a topological and not metric properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a famous open problem : If $d$ is an intrinsic metric on
Euclidean 2-dimensional ball, then it is a limit of increasing
Finsler metrics ?

[link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243080811_Two_counterexamples_in_low-dimensional_length_geometry)

Comment: Okay but is there a well-known subclass?